# Conversion factors for flux

Tags: luminosity, spectra, units, wavelength

I have a flux value in the infrared band of `8 mJy` at a wavelength of `80` microns that I want to translate into X-ray conventional flux of `keV/cm^2/s/keV`.
I have tried many conversion factors but none of them is helpful (see e.g. https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~pgreen/figs/Conversions.pdf). This table for example gives a conversion factor of $10^{-26}$ from `mJy` to `erg/cm^2/s/Hz`, and this is correct. However, when I go from `erg/cm^2/s/Hz` to `keV/cm^2/s/keV`, an additional $10^{26}$ factor comes out from the transformation of `ergs` and `Hz`. This cancels out with the previous factor and an unbelievable IR flux results, higher than the actually measured X-ray flux.

I know that the IR flux is much less than the X-ray flux, but can not find an appropriate way to convert.

Comment: It depends on the object emitting the radiation, no? For example, a lightbulb will emit most of its energy in the infrared, with some visible light, whereas a medical X-ray tube will emit most of its energy in the X-ray band and basically none at other wavelengths.